# ASP.NET 2.0 required field validator - Enabling and disabling

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0

I have textboxes with required field validtor. I have add button.

I have a grid with Edit and Delete link button.

On click of add button the RFValidator is correctly fired. However, When I click the edit button (after clicking the add button and RFValidator fired) on the grid. It should populate the textboxes with values but it doesn't. How can this be implemented.

I appreciate your support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the `Edit` button set to `CausesValidation="False"` ?

```
<asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Edit" CausesValidation="False"></asp:Button>
```

Comment: I thought I had that entered but I didn't. That did it. thank you!